# c# memory leak analyze

Tags: c#

I am breaking my head, but still I dint get solution. I ran these code and analyzed with .NET memory profiler. It showed me that one instance of IntEntity[] is not collected. But I am clearing the list and setting it to null. How I can make this to garbage collect? Am I doing anything wrong here?

Edit: I tried setting b = null & calling GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration); But same results.
Edit2: Added images from NET Memory Profiler & ANTS Memory profiler

Please help me.

Here is the code am using,

```
public class IntEntity
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    protected List<IntEntity> numbers;

    public Base()
    {
    }

    public abstract void Populate();

    public int Sum()
    {
        numbers = new List<IntEntity>();

        Populate();

        int sum = 0;
        foreach (IntEntity number in numbers)
        {
            sum += number.Value;
        }

        numbers.Clear();
        numbers = null;

        return sum;
    }
}

public class Child : Base
{
    public override void Populate()
    {
        numbers.Add(new IntEntity() { Value = 10 });
        numbers.Add(new IntEntity() { Value = 20 });
        numbers.Add(new IntEntity() { Value = 30 });
        numbers.Add(new IntEntity() { Value = 40 });
    }
}

 Base b = new Child();
 MessageBox.Show(b.Sum().ToString());
 b = null;
 GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since `Base` class here is abstract there must be some other code required for diagnosis, yes?

Comment: There's no real need to call `numbers.Clear()`.  Just setting `numbers=null` will cause the list to be collected and `IntEntity` references removed the next time the garbage collector does its thing.

Comment: There must be something else in the code that is missing from your sample.

Comment: Are you sure that the garbage collector was actually invoked?  Perhaps it just hadn't got around to collecting things yet.

Comment: @Jim: Good point. Maybe they should force a GC, just for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: How did you determine that there is a memory leak?

Comment: I don't see any case of IntEntity is not collected, may be you are using IntEntity somewhere else

Comment: IntEntity is not used anywhere. Only in these code. I dont know why the tool says that it is not collected. Actually in my application it showed for all List<T> objects. So to get the problem I tried a sample program like this and in this sample program itself it shows that it is not collected.

Comment: When collecting Heap snapshot the tool itself forces a GC. Anyway I did call GC.

Comment: What else is in the `IntEntity` class? Simply wrapping an integer like this makes no sense, so I assume that there is something else in this class?

Comment: IntEntity is just for sample. I know the sample program can be done better. But here we need to look why it is not collected and two memory profiler points out that. You can try out the sample, if you have time :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jim Mische and Steven Sudit pointed out it may be that the GC may simply not be collecting because the RAM available to the runtime is greater than the amount of memory required by the program

You can add GC.Collect() after setting numbers to null and it should probably disappear from your profile.

You should note that typically you should only induce a Garbage Collection for testing purposes only.

Comment: "You should note that typically you should only induce a Garbage Collection for testing purposes only"... Why?

Comment: Because Microsoft spent a lot of time figuring out when the GC runs and it does a pretty good job.